# How can I get into physics?

Tags: phd, masters, career-path, physics, changing-fields

I completed my undergraduate studies in economics a couple of years ago, and have since worked in finance (in the private and public sectors). Alongside my full-time work, I’ve pursued a master’s degree in energy economics and post-bac in computer science. I am reasonably comfortable with college-level math and programming, and while I was previously disinclined toward math as an undergraduate, I am now very interested in dealing with more challenging math.

For a variety of reasons, I've grown increasingly interested in trying to get into physics – as mentioned above, I've started to enjoy math as a late-bloomer; in my public sector work, I work a lot of with technologies and concepts from engineering, physics, and chemistry, and would like to better understand these concepts. I feel that a stronger grounding in the natural sciences would give me more credibility in my career.

If I do find that I very much enjoy learning about physics, and would like to pursue it at a graduate level, how would I even go about that, as someone several years out of undergrad? It seems to me that I would need to (a) complete an undergraduate-level physics program, (b) pursue at least a master's degree in physics, and – if I wanted to go down the PhD route – develop a record of physics research. I am just trying to understand the feasibility of such a career and educational switch.

Comment: MIT OpenCourseware: https://ocw.mit.edu/

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. I removed one of your questions since: 1) This site works only with one question per question. 2) That question was what we call a [shopping question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3657/7734) and thus not suited for this site.

Comment: Where are you based? there are programs from universities aimed at people like you. See https://www.port.ac.uk/collaborate/business/train-your-workforce/work-based-degrees-for-employers